# ListView - Custom Adapter - Values keep changing when scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-adapter

Android 2.3.3

I am using a Custom Adapter to fill a listview. Each row in a listview has 3 textviews(Custom Layout), that are filled from the data retrieved from database.

The problem is, the data is being displayed correctly, the first time. But when I scroll down and then scroll up the listview again, the rows at the top of the listview are replaced by the rows at the bottom and when I scroll down, they are again being replaced by the rows that are currently being displayed.

I thought the problem could be recreation of the rows and I should use viewHolder. Even though I did use the viewHolder, it doesn't solve the problem.

Here is the code...

```
class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return c.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HistoryViewHolder viewHolder;

            if(convertView == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
                convertView =  li.inflate(R.layout.history_row, null);

                viewHolder = new HistoryViewHolder();

                viewHolder.txtcnt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtView_History_Count);
                viewHolder.txtexp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtView_History_Expression);
                viewHolder.txtres = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtView_History_Result);

                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            else
            {
                viewHolder = (HistoryViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }


            if(!c.isAfterLast())
            {

                viewHolder.txtcnt.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));        
                System.out.println("Position"+viewHolder.txtcnt.getText().toString());

                expression = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("expression"));
                result = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("result"));

                c.moveToPosition(position + 1);

                viewHolder.txtexp.setText(expression);
                System.out.println("Expression"+viewHolder.txtexp.getText().toString());
                viewHolder.txtres.setText(result);      
                System.out.println("Result"+viewHolder.txtres.getText().toString());

            }   

        return convertView;
    }


    public class HistoryViewHolder {
        TextView txtcnt;
        TextView txtexp;
        TextView txtres;
    }

}
```

Am I using the viewHolder correctly? Why do we need to use the viewHolder? What is the use exactly?

EDIT ::: As suggested by vmironov ::: I have removed the `if(!c.isAfterLast())` and changed the `c.moveToPosition(position + 1)` to `c.moveToPosition(position)`. Now, the replacement doesn't happen, but the first element is being repeated twice and the last entry is not being displayed. And when i scroll down and up again, the first two rows are not being displayed.

EDIT 2 ::: Just moved the `c.moveToPosition(position)` above expression = `c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("expression"));`

I am posting the entire code, if needed have a look...

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    HistoryViewHolder viewHolder;

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
            convertView =  li.inflate(R.layout.history_row, null);

            viewHolder = new HistoryViewHolder();

            viewHolder.txtcnt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtView_History_Count);
            viewHolder.txtexp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtView_History_Expression);
            viewHolder.txtres = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtView_History_Result);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder = (HistoryViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

            viewHolder.txtcnt.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));        
            System.out.println("Position"+viewHolder.txtcnt.getText().toString());

            c.moveToPosition(position);

            expression = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("expression"));
            result = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("result"));

            viewHolder.txtexp.setText(expression);
            System.out.println("Expression"+viewHolder.txtexp.getText().toString());
            viewHolder.txtres.setText(result);      
            System.out.println("Result"+viewHolder.txtres.getText().toString());            


    return convertView;
}


public class HistoryViewHolder {
    TextView txtcnt;
    TextView txtexp;
    TextView txtres;
}
```

}

Comment: try to remove `if (!c.isAfterLast())` condition and replace `c.moveToPosition(position + 1)` with `c.moveToPosition(position)`

Comment: I did what you said. Still a minor problem I suppose. I have edited the question, please have a look at it.

Comment: I found the problem. `c.moveToPosition(position)` must be called before `expression = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("expression"));`

Comment: Problem Solved... Thanks a lot... If you can post it as an answer, I will accept it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove `if (!c.isAfterLast())` condition.
2. Replace `c.moveToPosition(position + 1)` with `c.moveToPosition(position)`
3. `c.moveToPosition(position)` must be called before `expression = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("expression"))`